plotly - replace first and last yticks with min and max value
I would like to mark max/min value as yticks like below:
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

def save_fig(fig,pngname):
    fig.write_image(pngname,format="png",width=800,height=500, scale=1)
    print("[[%s]]"%pngname)
    #fig.show()
    return

DATE='Date'
VAL='AAPL.High'
url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv'

def main():
    df = pd.read_csv(url)
    fig = px.line(df, x=DATE, y=VAL)
    for val in [df[VAL].min(),df[VAL].max()]:
        fig.add_hline(
            y=val, 
            annotation_text=f"{val:.2f}",
            line_width=.5,line_color='grey',
            annotation_position="left")
    

    print(df[VAL].min())
    save_fig(fig,"/media/sf_work/demo.png")
    return

main()


`
But current solution the min/max ticks will overlap. how can I replace start and end ticks with the min,max value instead of add a new one to avoid such overlap? Maybe read current ticks array then replace first and last value but not sure how to do it.

i am confused, you wish to see max/min in x-axis or y-axis? please simplify your questions

The threshold values from the minimum and maximum values are specified as a scale, and then the minimum and maximum horizontal lines are added, so that the scale goes from the minimum to the maximum value.offset=10;fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=[i for i in np.arange(df[VAL].min()-offset, df[VAL].max()-offset, offset)])
